# background color transition delay at the end of the event

Tags: html, css

Can I implement a transition delay on background-color at the end so that the background color stays for the mentioned delay?

Normally using `transition: background-color 500ms;` in CSS makes the delay at the beginning causing the delay time to start the transition. But I wanted the delay to appear at the end. Is there another properties to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you want the delay to appear at the end of the transition? Do you want something else to happen after the transition is over?

Comment: can you show some image of output , so easily understand, do you need delay in transition